# Merge fields laravel collections

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two Laravel collections. Mi first collection called **$custom_product**:

```
Collection {#313 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "custom_description" => "insert description here"
    ]
  ]
}
```

And I have my other collection called **$api_product**:

```
Collection {#311 ▼
  #items: array:29 [▼
    "article_id" => 5570
    "active" => null
    "name" => "CORBATA POLIESTER"
    "detail" => "- Pesa: 43 gr."
    "constructor_name" => "gift"
    "stock_available" => true
    "stock" => null
    "prices" => array:6 [▶]
    "price_pvp" => 29.0
    "size" => "1410X100"
  ]
}
```

I want this result. The same collection but with the field custom_description added:

```
Collection {#311 ▼
  #items: array:29 [▼
    "article_id" => 5570
    "active" => null
    "custom_description" => "insert description here"//add this field
    "name" => "CORBATA POLIESTER"
    "detail" => "- Pesa: 43 gr."
    "constructor_name" => "gift"
    "stock_available" => true
    "stock" => null
    "prices" => array:6 [▶]
    "price_pvp" => 29.0
    "size" => "1410X100"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `put` method of 
[laravel collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-put).

```
$collection = collect(['product_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Desk']);

$collection->put('price', 100);

$collection->all();

// ['product_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can itarete over collections and add fields manually as with simple array:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($secondCollection); $i++) {
    // Add field to an item.
    $secondCollection[$i]['custom_description'] = $firstCollection[$i]['custom_description'];
}
```

This code will give an idea. Actual code is really depends on collections structure.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you were doing this per individual record using the examples given, I think it would be:

```
$api_product->put($custom_product->toArray()[0]);
```

If you wanted to combine multiple records you could use the map() method

```
$api_products_collection->map(function($key,$item) {
    //combine the record
    return $item;
});
```